# jQuery on event find the element on other page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I m having 2 pages `index.html` and `genres.html`.
I have list of categories on `index.html` page, and also a detail about each of this list items on `genres.html`.
Now on click of any 1 category from list on `index.HTML` i want it to redirect me on `genres.HTML` page and **highlight the detail of clicked category** from `index.html` page.
Now can this be done with HTML CSS and jQuery?
I tried doing above things but sum-one told me you need to use php for it as my project is in PHP

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? Hint: on index.html, set a parameter in the URL like `genres.html?category=x`, on genres.html, read the URL and highlight using a library like http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the links look like:

```
<a href='genres.html#specific-category'>Specific category</a>
<a href='genres.html#other-category'>Other category</a>
```

On page genres.html have

```
<div id='specific-category'>Information</div>
<div id='other-category'>Information</div>
```

Then you can access the window.location.hash to get `#specific-category`.
So you can:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(window.location.hash).anything_you_want_the_effect_to_be();
}
```

It will also make the page scroll to the category which you want to highlight.

Comment: thnx @kuncajs. this was much easier option.

Answer (score 0):

Do it by linking genres.html?category="nameOfCategory" for each of the categories in index.html

On your genres.html page, you can see which one was passed in javascript by calling

```
var selectedCategory = getURLParameter("category");
```

Make sure you include this function in your head:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in few steps using the relative path and javascript/jquery.

1. pass some parameter with URL :
   EX:  http://test.com/project?hightlight=id1
2. When the page loads grab the url and get the value of the parameter.
   Ex : hightlight=id1.
3. You can use animate to show animation for that div.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom, and here's the QueryString function I use:

```
function getQuerystring(key, default_)
{
  if (default_==null) default_="";
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}
```

So on Index.html, you have links like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="Genres.html?g=genre1#genre1">Genre 1 - Foo</a></li>
<li><a href="Genres.html?g=genre2#genre2">Genre 2 - Bar</a></li>
<li><a href="Genres.html?g=genre3#genre3">Genre 3 - Etc</a></li>
</ul>
```

And on Genres.html you have this (using jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(dcoument).ready(function(){
    var genre = getQuerystring('g');
    $("#" + genre).addClass("highlight");
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .highlight { color: Red; font-size: 28px; }
</style>


<div id="genre1">
    Stuff on Genre 1
</div>

<div id="genre2">
    Stuff on Genre 2
</div>

<div id="genre3">
    Stuff on Genre 3
</div>
```